# do a random method that create imageViews randomly with more probabilities for one of the image

Tags: iphone, xcode, random, timer, uiimageview

I Have an uIImageView 'image1' that is created every seconds with a timer. I have also another uIImageView 'image2'. What I would like is that appears on the screen randomly every seconds 'image1' or 'image2'instead of only 'image1' and also that 'image1' has more chances to appear on the screen like (80 % more). How can I do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do a random between 5 values instead of 2. For 1 of these 5 values, you will choose image2, and for all 4 other values, you will choose image1

Comment: it is impossible to do it in another way ? because I was afraid someone give this response :).This way is easy to do but take more memory and I wanted to use a 'value ' to change during the app 80% to 50% then to 90% for example and with your  way it would be hard to change

Comment: Then do a `r=arc4random()%100` to pick a random number in range `[0-100[`, and compare it with the percentage value you need. If at one point you need image1 to be 80% more often than image2, then choose image1 if `r<80`, image2 otherwise. If at another point you need another percentage, use the appropriate value in your comparison. Simple as that.